# Photo sharing site (alternative to Flickr) supporting OpenID sign in?

Tags: webapp-rec, openid, photo-sharing

I'm looking for a web application to share my photos. The thing that turns me away from Flickr is my general tiredness from maintaining the ever growing user name/passwords list. As a general solution to the latter problem I have started using OpenID as my preferred method of login.

So my requirements are:

1. Photo Sharing web application
2. one that supports logins with an OpenID. 
   *Edit: to clarify I do not count Facebook Connect, Google OAuth and Yahoo credentials OpenID, I'd like to be able to use a true independent service such as myopenid.com to login.*
3. reasonable privacy control. i.e. I do not share all my photos with the entire universe
4. a free service would be nice, but I will consider paying for a decent implementation of 2 and 3 above.

p.s. already looked in [OpenID.com directory listings](https://www.myopenid.com/directory) just to be disappointed with zooomr.com (link removed due to Stack Exchange noob policy) that no longer accepts new members until "the first quarter of 2010" which one would think is already past us :)

Comment: I can't even fathom why Zooomr still exists. I like Kris as a person, but there is just so much terrible in that site. Flickr code and art theft notwithstanding. You were right to be disappointed with it/pass on it, as much as I may hate to say it.

Comment: I hate to say that I don't know who Kris is and what's the story behind zooomr, to be honest I'm intrigued now and will have a look. I was disappointed It was closed for registration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Ipernity](http://www.ipernity.com/) uses OpenID.

There are several that allow signing in with Facebook credentials (such as [Photobucket](http://photobucket.com/)). And, of course, everyone in the world has a Google account, so there is [PicasaWeb](http://picasaweb.google.com).

Comment: Thanks this is good info, I'm still not accepting this as the answer as I hope to hear some more suggestions, in particular I don't like the amount of details Ipermity requires in order to sign up with the service.